How to resolve "CMake Error at /opt/ros/humble/share/rosidl_cmake/cmake/rosidl_generate_interfaces.cmake:229"
When I am trying to build a package with:
CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(my_msgs)
find_package(rosidl_default_generators REQUIRED)
find_package(geometry_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(std_msgs REQUIRED)
rosidl_generate_interfaces(${PROJECT_NAME}
  "msg/ArrayPoseStampedWithCovariance.msg"
  DEPENDENCIES std_msgs geometry_msgs
)

ament_export_dependencies(rosidl_default_runtime)
ament_package()

and:
package.xml 
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package format="3">
    <name>my_msgs</name>
    <version>0.0.0</version>
    <description>TODO: Package description</description>
    <maintainer email="mats@todo.todo">mats</maintainer>
    <license>TODO: License declaration</license>

    <buildtool_depend>ament_cmake</buildtool_depend>
    <build_depend>rosidl_default_generators</build_depend>
    <depend>std_msgs</depend>
    <depend>geometry_msgs</depend>
    
    <exec_depend>rosidl_default_runtime</exec_depend>
    <exec_depend>rosidl_runtime_py</exec_depend>
    
    <test_depend>ament_lint_auto</test_depend>
    <test_depend>ament_lint_common</test_depend>

    <export>
        <build_type>ament_cmake</build_type>
        <member_of_group>rosidl_interface_packages</member_of_group>
    </export>
</package>

The below error is occurring:
CMake Error at /opt/ros/humble/share/rosidl_cmake/cmake/rosidl_generate_interfaces.cmake:229 (message):
  Packages installing interfaces must include
  '<member_of_group>rosidl_interface_packages</member_of_group>' in their
  package.xml
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:8 (rosidl_generate_interfaces)

How to resolve it?

You need to move <member_of_group>rosidl_interface_packages</member_of_group> line after <exec_depend>rosidl_default_runtime</exec_depend>.
